# Did the special nature of Chat contribute to the recent blow-up between two participants here?

Tags: discusión

Recently two users had a falling out.  Both ended up hurt, angry and shaken.  I know very little about what precipitated it.  But what I want to ask is, what role, if any, did the special nature of Chat (La Tertulia) play in how this played out?  This is by necessity a subjective question.

I'm asking because I have some vague, limited awareness that a site, I think it was IPS, had its chat shut down at some point, which might be an indication that chat has special characteristics, that may contribute to greater or quicker escalation of conflict.  I don't know if that was the case in our Tertulia.  At this stage, I'm wondering if it was.

Comment: I think this is something that applies globally to every chat around, so you could as well ask this question in [meta.SE], you will get lots of good answers if you do. See [the question I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338462/350184) there as a consequence of this same blow-up.

Comment: @Charlie - Unfortunately the answers you got there didn't seem particularly helpful, in my opinion.  They were very abstract.  I wanted to know, if two participants are rapidly escalating a conflict in the general Chat, what, if anything, should a bystander do, and what, if anything, should a moderator do?  I think people weren't able to say more than extremely broad generalities because they weren't given any parameters about what happened.  // I'm in the middle of a 7-day suspension on Meta.SE (an unjust one, in my opinion), so I can't ask anything there. // I tend to avoid Chat everywhere..

Comment: ... however, in Academia when the comment chain gets quite long, the moderators there tend to move everything to Chat, and I've seen that in that hidden space, bad behavior can get quite a bit worse.  I have the vague impression there's a different threshold for flags to be processed when they're raised in Chat -- which makes no sense to me.  I once saw in a transferred Academia chat about a gender issue, there was somebody behaving very trollishly and I kept raising flags but nothing was happening. // I don't know whether any flags were raised in the recent incident.

Comment: I'm sorry about your suspension there, I heard about that but I didn't know it was still ongoing. But you are talking about incidents in the main chat in IPS, also in small chats in Academia, so my point is, IMHO, valid. This is a question that applies network-wide. We can try to answer it here if you want, but I strongly recommend that you wait until the end of your suspension and then ask in MSE. About our incident, no flags were raised but I ended up deleting the worst part.

Comment: El chat solo es una herramienta donde poder conversar en tiempo real. En este caso el conflicto no se inicio en el chat, el primer desencuentro, que yo sepa, fue en las candidaturas a moderador y más recientemente fue por comentarios en una pregunta. A través del chat se puede resolver un conflicto o agravarlo pero eso ya depende de los interlocutores como en cualquier situación en la vida. Las herramientas nunca son culpables del comportamiento de las personas y como estas las utilizan.

Comment: @Charlie - From reading your Meta SE question, I thought that you were questioning a lot of things, maybe more than you explicitly wrote?  Maybe you were wondering if you should have raised a flag, and then dealt with it in your new, fledgling moderator role; maybe you had hesitated to do any of that, for various, different reasons.  I wasn't sure if I was reading too much into it.  But I think that people often don't want their problems solved, and even if you had tried to break it up, sometimes people are on a collision course and nothing will change that.

Comment: @Charlie - I do think that it's not right for one brand new moderator to face something like that without co-moderators to help.  Also, I had the impression you tend to take weekends off the site, and it seemed like things blew up on the weekend. // I don't want to ask on Meta.SE because I don't think more vagueness and abstraction would help any of us process what happened here. // I have written to walen and he did respond once.  I don't know if he will again.  Desconozco las causas, pero tengo la impresión que estaba tal vez batallando sus propios demonios, y fedorqui por mala suerte...

Comment: ... got caught in the cross fire, no sí cómo decir eso....  Creo que él se dió cuenta que estaba fuera de control, y decidió protegerse de descontrolarse aún más, y proteger a fedorqui, y a todos aquí, y por eso decidió salirse.  Quién sabe.  Es una impresión nomás.  Espero que encuentre algo de paz con el tiempo.  @blonfu - ¿En cuál pregunta se dieron los comentarios que mencionas?

Comment: Pues ahora mismo no recuerdo qué pregunta era pero eso ya no es importante, no creo que seguir removiendo este tema ayude en nada a la situación por eso no he dado más detalles, solo he contestado aquí para eximir al chat de responsabilidad en el conflicto

Comment: If you ask on meta.se I suspect it will be closed as either a duplicate of @Charlie question or as opinion-based. I think letting sleeping dogs lie might be the best option here, as in so many situations in life.